# findOne is giving me and error in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

ErrorMessage:

```js
err: {
      "type": "MongooseError",
      "message": "Query was already executed: guilds.findOne({ name: 'Stream Squire' })",
```

Code:

```js
async function lookUpDB(guildName, lookFor) {
    
    const query = {name: guildName} 
    const guildModel = await model('guilds', GuildSchema)
    const guildFind =  guildModel.findOne(
        query,
        (err, doc) => {
            console.log(doc || err)
        }
    )
    return guildFind
    
}
```

Database Data:

[image]

Goal: I'm trying to make a function that will work anytime I need to find something in the database. Currently getting the error up top when i try to find the prefix. I'm not too familiar with mongoose or mongodb this is a discord bot to I was making to try and learn how to use it

Update:
Guild Schema

```
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose')

const GuildSchema = new Schema(
    {},
    {
        strict: false,
        versionKey: false,
    }
)




module.exports = { GuildSchema, model }
```

Database:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { logger } = require('../config/pino')
const { config } = require('../config/dotenv')
mongoose.connect(
    //removed info 
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
)
const { connection: db } = mongoose

db.on('connected', () => {
    logger.info('Database connected')
})

db.on('disconnected', () => {
    logger.info('Database disconnected')
})

db.on('error', (err) => {
    logger.error(err)
})

module.exports = { db }
```

Comment: No need of await when you are using the callback function. So you are executing twice, hence the error message.

Comment: I removed the await but still seem to get the same error

Comment: Try changing ```const guildModel = await model('guilds', GuildSchema)``` to ```const guildModel = mongoose.model('guilds', GuildSchema)```

Comment: Still no luck. I have mongoose declared in another file though

Comment: Can you show your schema declared file?

Comment: I updated it to show the other files.

Comment: Specify the schema and try it like i have written in the answer below.

Comment: I'll try it when I get home from work. Would I have to define the guild named object as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, by convention, if you dont already have a Schema file declared create one,something like,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const schemaDefinition = {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    botName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    Users:[{
        type: String
    }],
    //add the rest
}

const GuildSchema = new Schema(schemaDefinition);
module.exports = mongoose.model('guilds', GuildSchema);
```

And then in your API logic file,export this schema model,

```
const GuildsModel = require('path to file');


async function lookUpDB(guildName, lookFor) {
    
    const query = {name: guildName} 
    const guildFind =  GuildsModel.findOne(
        query,
        (err, doc) => {
            console.log(doc || err)
        }
    )
    return guildFind
    
}
```

Comment: Sorry been having issues with my internet at home thank you for the help it worked. I ended up doing a schema for each instead though.

Comment: Great! @JoeLong